# how to use 'group by' on hql?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, native

I have a native query I need to change to HQL.

The original query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `table`.`id`) FROM `database`.`table` WHERE
(`table`.`date`" " BETWEEN '" + year + "-01-01 00:00:00' AND '" + year
+ "-12-31 23:59:59') AND `table`.`box` NOT LIKE '' GROUP BY MONTH(`table`.`date`)";
```

I tried something like:

```
StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder(); 
hql.append(" select count(distinct table.id)"); 
hql.append(" from Table table");
hql.append(" where table.date between '?-01-01 00:00:00' and '?-12-31 23:59:59'");
hql.append(" and table.box not like ''"); 
hql.append("group by month (table.date)"); 
query.setParameter(1, Integer.toString(year)); 
query.setParameter(2, Integer.toString(year));
```

Where year is a int passed to the method as argument.

The generated query is:

```
Hibernate: select count(distinct table0_.id) as col_0_0_ from table table0_ where (table0_.date between '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-12-31 23:59:59') and (table0_.box not like '') group by month(table0_.date)
```

My problem is: using the native query, I get one value and using the hql I get another for month 2 (February). For month 1 (January) results are the same.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance,

gtludwig

Comment: have you enabled logging of hibernate SQL generation to see if what it is generating? (logger=org.hibernate.SQL)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the original question to show this output as well.

Comment: They seem to be the same query without the schema qualification to me. Aren't you running them in different instance? Like, one in 'database' and the other pointing to anoher base with similar data loaded?

Comment: Indeed it seems I was testing on a old test database which hadn't been updated in a while, thus the difference. Thanks for the time and the insights!

Comment: Gonna post it as answer then :) You could, accept it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to be the same query without the schema qualification to me. Aren't you running them in different instance? Like, one in 'database' and the other pointing to anoher base with similar data loaded?